# Python3.6 installed but version showing as 3.5.2

Tags: python, linux, heroku, command-line, python-3.6

I am on an Ubuntu virtual machine and I am trying to update my version of python on the command line. I followed the instructions [here](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install3/linux/)
and eventually ran `$ sudo apt-get install python3.6` but when I run `python3 --version` it tells me my python version is 3.5.2

I am following a tutorial on heroku about building a web app using python for the server side and it says I need python3.6 installed. But when I got to the step where it was really needed, I found out it wasn't actually installed.

Any ideas?

Comment: try using `python3.6`

Comment: Also, you install an entirely new interpreter, the old one is still there, being pointed to by `python3`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga what?? The whole point of this is to try to use python3.6, what are you talking about

Comment: I just told you what you did: you installed an entirely new interpreter, python 3.6, but your old python 3.5.2 interpreter is still there. Like I said, try using `python3.6`

Comment: In other words, if you did `sudo apt-get install python3.6` and it seemed to have worked, then Python 3.6 **is almsost certainly installed*, it's just that the binary isn'y being found in your path at `python3`.

Comment: python probably put itself in the path twice. both "executeables" are called python3 - it finds the old one first. uninstall that one so the other one is found. or remove the old dir from path if you want to keep it

Comment: Found the answer here:
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/07/install-python-3-6-1-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts/

There are a couple steps the first walkthrough was missing

Comment: @PatrickArtner probably better to use debian `update_alternatives` to manage that.

Answer (score 5):

Installing the python3.6 package doesn't touch your existing system Python installation.  Python 3.5 is still installed as you saw by the output of `$python3 --version`. To invoke Python 3.6, you can use: `$python3.6`